# How to add footer and header to other views using routerLayout in java using vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I created a class named "Footer" having just a Label. I also have a few views like loginview, orderview). And I would like to add that footer to every view. This is my code until now.

```
@ParentLayout(OrderView.class)
public class footer extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {
    public footer() {
     add(new Span("This text should be underneath the page in the views"));
    }
}
```

Underneath you have my orederview where I want to see that text from the footerclass.

```
@Route("order")
public class OrderView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {

    public OrderView (){
   // What am I supposed to code here to get that text from Footerclass.
        
    }
}
```

I would like to know what I am missing.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `footer()` constructor does not really do anything meaningful.

Comment: You should add that Label into the layout that you are extending.

Comment: jmizv, Thats what the exercise asks... just add a text below each view I have.

Comment: Anna, how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: It's just `add(label);`

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of the annotations is wrong. Here is super simplified outline how you should create MainLayout and route that defines a component that is shown in the mainlayout when navigated to that route.

```
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {

    private Div childWrapper = new Div();

    public void MainLayout() {
        setSizeFull();
        Span header = new Span("This text should be above the page in the views");
        Span footer = new Span("This text should be underneath the page in the views");
        add(header);
        addAndExpand(childWrapper)
        add(footer);             
    }

    @Override
    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
        childWrapper.getElement().appendChild(content.getElement());
    }
}

@Route(value = "order", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class OrderView extends VerticalLayout {

    public OrderView (){
    }
}
```

There is [video tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-router) about Router concept on vaadin.com page that explains this in detail.

Comment: Tatu, Thank you ... Is it possible, for example, in class orderView to have more then one layout? for example: @Route(value = "order", layout = MainLayout.class, layout = Seconsclass.class)?

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming for with that? But you can have multiple routes defined for a class. One with `@Route`, and other routes with `@RouteAlias`, and yes with `@RouteAlias` you can define other layout. Watch the tutorial I linked fully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new Label("This text should be underneath the page in the views");
```

try

```
add(new Span("This text should be underneath the page in the views"));
```

In Vaadin Flow the Label component is meant to be used coupled with another component, not for adding stand-alone text like in Vaadin 8 and older. Also, every component needs to be added to the layout before they can become visible, just creating them isn't enough.

Unfortunately LoginOverlay doesn't have API for adding extra components within it, but there is an open ticket about the feature that you can add thumbs up on to add more weight to it, and there's also a workaround presented in the comments: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/626

Comment: Anna, I added span to it, but how can i get that text in the loginview?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that part. Modified the answer.

Comment: I understood that. But I have another view(orderview) and it just extends verticallayout and implelents RouterLayout... To get that footer text into this class(orderview)... I just added into the contructor: addElement(Footer.class, "footer")... but it doesnt work.

Comment: I just remembered that in Vaadin Flow the LoginOverlay is indeed an overlay (the name really should have been a hint), so you can't use that workaround. Adjusting my answer again.